# Would it be a good practice or just unnecessary to wrap mixpanel or something similar in wrapper?

Tags: javascript, mixpanel

Hi I'm about to implement mixpanel in a application. I thought that I might wrap it another function or object  so that I could get more control of it and that it would be easier to edit if there would be any changes in the future.

But I'm not sure if that would me true in the end, would it just make me write unnecessary code instead of just using mixpanel library directly.

What's your thougts?
What would be the best practice?

Answer (score 0):

I just did something similar to this for the same reasons. I can't see any harm. If you're making the same call in multiple places within the app, this is a way of keeping it Dry. I'm building a Django app, and placed it inside a simple util file with a method that looks like

```
def track(user_id, event_name, circumstances={}):
    mp.track(user_id, event_name, circumstances)
```